# Whats the proper setup for this node.js module

Tags: node.js, module

https://npmjs.org/package/jsoncomp

https://github.com/tcorral/JSONC

This module looks really great! It compresses JSON and gzips it droping upto around 80% of the size.

I've managed to use only the compressor so far (but I have noticed a significant speed increase).

The problem comes up when I try and JSONC.pack(compressedjson) and it throws errors because the main file (JSONC.js) is in a folder called src and the files it somehow uses* are in a folder called vendor.

It comes up with Base64 is undefined.

*I can't see for the life of me how these js file are suppose to link up when Base64 is never declared and there's not even a reference to ../vendor/base64.js

The same goes for gzip.js and I expect the 3 other js files in the vendor folder...

Has anyone here used this? The docs are missing the part where you plug it in...

I've asked the owner also but someone must know as there are 209 stars on git hub.

I'm the first person to put a Issue also on this git repo. I know I'm not totally thick but how has noone out of at least 209 people not had this issue??

Comment: I am not sure if it is used widely. But this is something done via [zlib](http://nodejs.org/api/zlib.html). [express.compress](http://expressjs.com/api.html#compress) also does it on the fly for you, if you are using express.

Comment: then why this module so popular??

Comment: I don't think it is popular in that sense. Stars help in keeping track  of projects a person is interested in, that is keen to work on or follows. It's good if you are a developer.

Comment: right i see, I think the gzip part must be fore the client side only then as node has zlib

Comment: Ben, browser can decode http bodies automatically, so you don't really need to bother about finding a module to compress json. Just set appropriate headers.